# Recursively find the number of files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Recursively find the number of files in a directory.

For example, if directory `one` has directory `12 directories` and each of these `12 directories` have another `13 directories`.
and the grandchild (13 directories) has a fixed number of files. 
How do I find how many it has?

I am trying to visualize the output in the following fashion:

```
a/b/1/ -- 50 files
a/b/2/ -- 10 files
a/c/1/ -- 20 files.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s " "$0"; find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf x | wc -c' {} \;
```

and for your specific formatting:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'n=$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf x | wc -c); printf "%s -- %s files\n" "$0" "$n"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`find . -type f | wc -l`

(it counts the output lines (wc-l) of a the output of a command (find . -type f) that outputs a line per file in the tree)

**[EDIT]** After reading your comment and updates I came up with this one liner:

`tree -idf --noreport | while read line ; do echo $line ; find $line -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l ; done`

Comment: That just gave the output of the number of files. I want per folder.

Comment: A few problems in this answer: the output of `tree` is not meant to be parsed; will miserably fail with spaces (lacks of quotes) or other funny symbols (newlines).

Comment: In that case I guess it could be replaced with `find . -type d` then. Anyway the accepted answer is much better than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in 1000000 1200000 1400000 1600000 1800000 2000000 2200000 2400000 800000
    do
    for b in 10 14 18 2 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 6
    do
        echo $a-$b
        find $a/$a-$b/ -type f -print | wc -l
    done
done
```

Comment: I'm the author. I thought this was one way of doing it.